# How to search polymorphic JSON objects in c#?

Tags: c#, json, jsonconvert

Deserializing the following json

```
{
    "MetaData1": "hello world",
    "MetaData2": 2022,
    "Data": {
        "ObjectA": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "steve",
            "hobbies": 1
        },
        "ObjectB": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "dave",
            "age": 55
        }
    }
}
```

into corresponding c# objects

```
public class ObjectBase
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
public class ObjectA : ObjectBase
{
    public int hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB : ObjectBase
{
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public ObjectA ObjectA { get; set; }
    public ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string metaData1 { get; set; }
    public int metaData2 { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

using

```
Root object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

How could I search the `id` properties of the object properties of `Root.Data` for a matching `int` and return the corresponding `name` property.

It would also be useful to be able to create `List<ObjectBase>` so that other LINQ operations could be performed on these objects.

Comment: How about just adding all the properties to one type and deserializing into that instead? Some of the properties will be empty, but is that really a problem?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen how do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i think what i am ultimately after here is to end up with `List<ObjectBase>`.

This can be achieved easily with `System.Text.Json` (or Newtonsoft).

The most natural representation (IMO) given your Json structure would be to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, ObjectBase>`. Then you could convert the dictionary to a `List<ObjectBase>`. You need a class to match the `Data` element in your (updated) Json:

```
// 'root' class to represent the 'Data' element
public class Root
{
    public string MetaData1 { get; set; }
    public int MetaData2 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ObjectBase> Data { get; set; }
}

// Dictionary<string, ObjectBase>
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
foreach (var key in model.Data.Keys)
    // do something with model.Data[key].id/name

// convert to List<ObjectBase>
var list = new List<ObjectBase>(model.Data.Values);
```

---

Expanding on Lasse V. Karlsen's comment, you could instead add all properties to a single class and deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, SingleClass>`:

```
public class SingleClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int hobbies { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    // all other properties...
}
```

If you choose this method you may want to consider making the additional properties nullable (if you're interested in differentiating between no `hobbies` property or someone with `hobbies = 0`, for example).

The methods above will deserialize into either `ObjectBase` or the `SingleClass`.

[Demo online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIi5xT)

Comment: why cant you simply `var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ObjectBase>>(json)` (I have tested and this doesn't work).

then i don't understand why this does work
`var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, ObjectBase>>(json)`

how is Deserialize() deciding what is the string key for the dictionary?

Comment: The same technique works in both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.  If you're using System.Text.Json you'll need to take care with property name casing, or use `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute, or pass the correct `PropertyNamingPolicy` in the serializer options

Comment: surely the fact that i have constructed equivalent c# classes that represents this shows that i know this. what i dont understand is that in my mind, both List<T>, Dictionary<TKey,TValue> are both lists. they are even in the same namespace System.Collections.Generic. so why can one be used and not the other?

Comment: "but a collection of objects can't be deserialized into a list" i'm pretty sure it can if the object had a property that was an array of objects. what is an array if not a collection? "Your json represents an object (and nested objects), not an array (because there are no [])." so why can the nested objects be represented by a dictionary?

Comment: dont worry i think i puzzled it out. an array is a container for bunch of objects. but object properties have both names and and objects associated with them. so the dictionaries key represents the name, and the value represents the object. interesting that i cant find any documented examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Name only lookup

If you need to look up the `name` property based on the `id` then you can do that with the following code:

```
var semiParsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(json);
var name = (from node in semiParsed.Values
            let id = (int)node.GetValue("id")
            where id == lookupId
            select (string)node.GetValue("name"))
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(name);
```

- First we deserialize the json into a collection

  - The top most properties' name will be the keys of the `Dictionary`
  - The top most properties' object will be treated as `JObject`s (semi parsed jsons)
- Then we perform a [Linq to Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query

  - We iterate through the `JObject`s and retrieve their `id` property

    - `GetValue` returns a `JToken` and since we know it is a number, we cast it to `int`
  - We perform a filtering based on the `lookupId`
  - And we select the `name` property's value
- Finally we need to issue a `FirstOrDefault` method call because the previous query returns an `IEnumerable<string>`

Here I have assumed that the the `id` is unique. If the provided `lookupId` is not defined inside the json then the result will be `null`.

#### Wrapping object lookup

If you need to perform a look up for the wrapping object then you need to use [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) as well:

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schemaA = generator.Generate(typeof(ObjectA));
JSchema schemaB = generator.Generate(typeof(ObjectB));

var semiParsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(json);
var theNode = (from node in semiParsed.Values
            let id = (int)node.GetValue("id")
            where id == lookupId
            select node)
        .FirstOrDefault();

if (theNode == null)
    return;

if (theNode.IsValid(schemaA))
{
    var objA = theNode.ToObject<ObjectA>();
    Console.WriteLine(objA.hobbies);
} else if (theNode.IsValid(schemaB))
{
    var objB = theNode.ToObject<ObjectB>();
    Console.WriteLine(objB.age);
}
```

- First we generate two json schemas from the class definitions
- Then we perform almost the same query the only difference here is the `select` part

  - We return here the whole `JObject` object instead of just its name
- Finally perform a schema validation

  - If the retrieved json matches to `schemaA` then we can safely convert (`ToObject`) to `ObjectA`
  - We check the json against `schemaB` as well

Comment: please see my answer and see if you agree

Comment: @Dissolution Your are the only person among the answer posters who knows what's good for your particular use case and requirements.  Loading data into objects and using reflection for simple filtering seems a bit overkill. But as always: measure, measure and measure. Choose that one which is the most suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way would be convert your json to dictionary of JObjects, in this case you don't need any classes at all

```
var dict = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().ToDictionary(jo => jo.Value["id"],jo=>jo.Value);

var searchId=2;

var name = dict[searchId]["name"];  // dave
```

or you can deserialize json to list of c# objects

```
List<ObjectBase> list = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
.Select(jo => jo.Value.ToObject<ObjectBase>()).ToList();
```

and use linq to get data

Comment: please see my answer and see if you agree

Comment: @Dissolution I am sorry but reflections is the last choise, when nothing else can be working. Reflections take the most computers resources and have the lowest performance. I don' t  create any classes at all and my code is  only 2 lines.

Comment: doesn't my method have advantages? like i can then access other properties other than name related to that id? if i wanted to get more properties using your methods, i would have to repeatedly parse the json?

Comment: @Dissolution You just asked for the name, but I could return the whole object, not just name. Your code will never be working. It  can be only used in a high school , as an exersice

Comment: how can we get List<ObjectBase>?

Comment: @Dissolution Yes, check my updated answer

Comment: anyway we can do this with System.Text.Json?

Comment: i havent tested this because i didn't want to load json.net into my project or my test project. but i read the documentation and i think this would be an answer for people who prefer json.net to System.Text.Json even though i have ultimately accepted another answer as solved. i would upvote but i don't have enough rep

Answer (score -1):

This answer using reflection is poorly optimised as pointed out by serge in a reply to his answer.

```
foreach (var prop in root.GetType().GetProperties())
{

    var obj = prop.GetValue(root);

    if ((int) obj.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(obj) == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(obj).ToString());
        break;
    }

}
```

Another method that gets `List<ObjectBase>` using reflection

```
var objects = root.Data.Objects;
List<ObjectBase> objectList = objects.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>().ConvertAll(x => (ObjectBase)x.GetValue(objects));
```

I am going to leave this answer here incase it helps someone who can't get to this point by desterilisation (maybe their objects weren't crated by desterilisation).